# How to set alternative colors to gridview cells without extending BaseAdapter in Fragment

Tags: android, android-gridview

I want to set colors on alternate cells of my gridview which i have filled with arrayadapter items and i dont want to extend BaseAdapter class also:

**code i have used:**

```
     public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.MESSAGE";
   TextView selection;
      public int idToModify;
    DataManipulator dm;
   private GridView gridView;
    public static ArrayList<String> ArrayName = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Object[]> names2 = null;
 String[] stg1;
     String[] stgid;

  @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag2, container, false);
     }

   @Override
  public void onStart() {
  super.onStart();

   dm = new DataManipulator(getActivity());
   names2 = dm.selectAll();

   stg1 = new String[names2.size()];
   stgid = new String[names2.size()];
   int x = 0;

   for (Object[] name : names2) {
       stgid[x] = (String) name[0];
       stg1[x] = (String) name[1] + " - " + (String) name[2] + " - "
               + (String) name[3] + " - " + (String) name[4];
       x++;
   }

   gridView = (GridView) getView().findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
           getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stg1);

   gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

 }
}
 }
```

i also tried extending Base adapter class and successed but i am just filling gridview with arrayadapter and want to set colors to cells without extending code too much.Thanks

Comment: do you tried SimpleAdapter

Comment: nopes i didn't try let me search and do comment if u have ans

Comment: i want alternate colors on gridview cells while showing not when we click them??

Answer (score 0):

Instead of android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 one should pass your custom layout.

```
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(), R.layout.custom_layout, stg1);
```

Where custom_layout.xml can look like

```
 <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ef0"
  />
```